# You have an error in your SQL syntax, how to fix it?

Tags: java, mysql

I got this problem in process of showing data from MYSQL

### This is my code

```
       int row = 0;

       String sql = "SELECT * FROM db_transection INNER JOIN db_book ON  db_book.book_id = db_transection.book_id WHERE member_id = " + tx_member_id.getText() + " AND tran_type = 'borrow'";

        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            modelTran.addRow(new Object[0]);
            modelTran.setValueAt(rs.getInt("tran_id"), row, 0);
            modelTran.setValueAt(rs.getInt("book_id"), row, 1);
            modelTran.setValueAt(rs.getString("book_name"), row, 2);
            modelTran.setValueAt(rs.getInt("member_id"), row, 3);
            row++;
        }
        table_tranborrow.setModel(modelTran);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and it throws an error --

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND tran_type = 'borrow'' at line 1

how to fix it?

Comment: what is the datatype of member_id in database

Comment: member_id is datatype of int

Comment: and `tx_member_id.getText()` definitely returns an integer?

Comment: yes. it returns as an int

Comment: actually, what is `sql` set to, right before you execute it?

Comment: what do you mean? insert? or update?

Comment: I have 2 member_id(s). one belongs to db_member and its datatype is int(primary key) and another belongs to db_transection which is I mention and its datatype is int(not primary key)

Comment: i mean what is the full query, after you've built it, and before you execute it?

Comment: Put a System.out.println(sql) and post the result, I suspect that "tx_member_id.getText()" is empty.

Comment: SELECT * FROM db_transection INNER JOIN db_book ON db_book.book_id = db_transection.book_id WHERE member_id =  AND tran_type = 'borrow'

Comment: I system.out.print it and above is the result

Comment: Stop using concatenation for sql, use prepared statement!

Comment: why member_id is empty?

Comment: its your code. you tell us. there's nothing in your question that indicates how/when `tx_member_id` gets set,  but thats why your query doesnt work

Comment: 1. I've built 3 databases are 
1. db_member which inside
    1.1.member_id datatype Int primary key
    1.2.member_tel -->  String
    1.3.member_name -->String
    1.4.member_created_date --> Datetime
    1.5.member_id_card
2.db_book which inside
    2.1.book_id --> Int primary key
    2.2.book_name--> String
    2.3.book_created_date--> Datetime
3.db_transection which inside
    3.1.tran_id --> Int primary key
    3.2.member_id--> Int
    3.3.book_id--> Int
    3.4.tran_type-->ENUM(return , borrow)
    3.5.tran_return_date--> Datetime
    3.6.tran_borrow_date--> Datatime

Comment: 2.In this form is borrow form and  I've coded to show the information of transaction which I've built the table has 4 columns are 1. transaction's id , 2. book's id , 3. book's name 4. member's id and I've built 2 inputs from text fields ,are tx_member_id input ,and tx_book_id input.
As above code when I complied I input and after I clicked save button I got the error as above

Comment: and I System.out.print I got empty value although I input some number

Comment: it's able to insert to database but it's unable to show database in table

Comment: I guess the problem is empty value of tx_member_id

Comment: edit your question instead of adding comments

Comment: Sorry I am new here I dont know so much